# pass dom object to processing function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the following code, I am trying to pass the table cell (as a DOM object) to the function, but `this` doesn't mean the DOM object for the table cell, it appears that it refers to the `$scope`.  Any idea how to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<table>
  <tr >
    <td ng-click="dum();">ONE</td>
    <td>TWO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td ng-click="dum(this);">{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
obj1 = "haha";
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
    .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
    $scope.dum = function(x) { obj1 = x; console.log(x); }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not (have to) play around with DOM when using angular especially when doing most common stuff. That is what angular abstracts out via directives. If at all you need to, you do it in a directive. But for what you are doing here, no idea why do you need that element there. `this` is scope because scope has a property called `this` which points to itself

Comment: dont play with dom... you are not using angular as it should be

Comment: The problem is, in the handler code, I need to distinguish what cell I clicked.   Thanks.

Comment: @codingFun Why do you need the element though, for what purpose?. Just pass in the data. `dum(x)` or if you need to get the index use `$index` special property of ng-repeat. **If you access DOM in the angular controller, you are doing something wrong.**

Comment: you completely misunderstand how to use angular effectively.  Instead of passing `this`, you simply need to pass `x`, which is the specific object that is in that iteration of the `ng-repeat`.  If there are, say, 10 elements in the array, there will be 10 buttons, and each one will have one of the 10 elements assigned.

Comment: Thanks PSL and Claies.   That's good idea.  Learning something basics here.

Comment: @codingFun Then it is the right time to do it right.. ;) Have a read at the official [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#understanding-controllers) and [here is another](http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/) . You can also follow some styleguide esp the one from John Papa.

Comment: @PSL thanks again for your help. Now that I think of it, the suggestion by you and Claies are better:  all the useful data in DOM are there when creating the DOM element to be begin with, so there is no need to read a DOM element to get the data.   Wish I can accept your comment as answer.

Comment: @codingFun Awesome, you get it!!

Comment: also, I'm not sure why there was a downvote; even though the code isn't correct, it isn't a bad question; angular is a complex framework with a large learning curve, and it's not uncommon for people to approach it in the way they are used to with other frameworks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular, you should always code against your data.  Coding against the DOM is unnecessary in all but the most extreme edge cases, and when it is necessary, it's usually best done in a directive, where you can control how the rest of the angular app is updated.

In your case, you don't need to access the DOM, or the element, or even an event.  You already have all the information you need in order to handle your code with the data.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td ng-click="dum(x);">{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
</tr>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.dum = function(x) { console.log(x); }
```

Comment: @codingFun this is one of the most tricky aspects of angular to get used to, but once you can grasp the idea behind two way binding, it opens up a completely new appreciation for the framework itself, and gives you a new outlook on what is possible in a browser environment.

Comment: that's exactly right, especially for someone who works in other field (but has to do UI work too).  So glad to get help from you and PSL tonight.

Comment: @codingFun just keep in mind that in angular, your data is the official record, and that the HTML is there to support the data, and you'll be fine.  In some other frameworks, the HTML is the official record, which is why so many DOM manipulations occur.

Answer (score 1):

You could, probably, do this:

In your HTML

```
<td ng-click="dum($event);">{{ x.Name }}</td>
```

In your Javascript

```
$scope.dum = function(e) { obj1 = e.target; console.log(x); }
//e.target will be the clicked element.
```

Comment: Thank you @mindastic!  It works.  I will accept it in 7min due to SO rule.

Comment: @minidastic,  Just realized the best way is not to read the DOM element to get the data needed in processing.  I think your answer is a nice trick to know, since `$event` may contain something else that's useful (like position of clicking).

Comment: Actually, i didn't know what you had to do. I just answered a way of achieving what you wanted in your code. Anyway, i do totally agree that it is not the way of doing it in angular.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend accessing the DOM from a controller, but you can use the $event.target.  Here's a plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/wFdnPJVa7BHOcvkPqNNT?p=preview

```
angular.module('Test', [])
.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope)
{
  $scope.myFunc = function(e)
  {
    console.dir(e.target);
  }
}]);
```

And the HTML

```
<body ng-app="Test">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <button ng-click="myFunc($event)">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</body>
```